# How to return a Mono empty object such that it is accepted by the application/json format?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, mono

I am using an exception function for my http request. For my task I need to read the response and if it is giving Internal Server Error, we have to return a null object.
I tried using Mono.empty() as the exception function only takes mono as returned object.
But now I get the error for
`UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/html;charset=UTF-8' not supported`
Is there a way to return a Mono that is empty without encountering this error.

Comment: Please, share us come if you want us to help you

Comment: We definitely need code and not just a description of it.